# My application is going to hang when I try to write something in proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y")

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I try to execute command from c# code. But when I used proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y") my application is hang.

My code is below.

string command = "My command after execute it shows some output and required user entry";

```
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

        // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();


        string standard_output;
        while ((standard_output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (standard_output.Contains("Are you sure (Y/y or N/n ):"))
            {
                proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
                //do something
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while ((standard_output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (standard_output.Contains("Are you sure (Y/y or N/n ):"))
            {
                proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");
               string myReturn= proc.StandardInput.ReadLine();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for response but my debugger not come in if condition if I remove procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; then its coming but it throws exception in write

Comment: Its resolved now I put echo y in my command string and its working fine thanks :)

Comment: you got it.if this works please accept it as the answer!